# IIS hosted ASP.NET API fails after upgrading from ASP.Net Core 3.0 to .net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I have a simple API that I bumped from .NET Core 3.0 to .NET Core 3.1 hosted InProcess in IIS. All packages are updated to the latest version and the application works on my development machine both in release and debug.

There are no configuration or server changes done besides installing the new hosting bundle.

On the server I have installed “ASP.NET Core 3.1 Runtime (v3.1.1) - Windows Hosting Bundle” and the server is a VM with a fully patched server 2016 standard.

My API can serve static files (Swagger) successfully but any API request has been returned with status code 401 (Windows authentication) and then crashes the app pool without any logging. Nothing about the crash in my logging and the STDOUT logging for the .NET core is empty.

The only thing I get is in event viewer:

```bash
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time

stamp: 0x57899b8a Faulting module name: coreclr.dll, version:
4.700.19.60701, time stamp: 0x5debd517 Exception code: 0xc00000fd Fault offset: 0x00000000000d332d Faulting process id: 0x1bd8 Faulting

application start time: 0x01d5d20038929f92 Faulting application path:

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe Faulting module path: C:\Program

Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.1\coreclr.dll Report Id:

05869df6-8b2c-4b8a-b44a-eefe315d1559 Faulting package full name: 

Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

In my testing, there are different .dlls that crash (faulting module) for different releases/debug that I have done. From `unknown` to `System.Collections.Concurrent.dll` and `coreclr.dll`.

I have checked that the .NET core runtime is installed:

`dotNet –info` in cmd line returns

```bash
NET Core SDKs installed:   No SDKs were found.
 
.NET Core runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0

[C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]  

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program

Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App

3.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

My `web.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
        arguments=".***********.dll" 
        stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
        stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
        hostingModel="inprocess" >
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="WEBCONNECTION_DETAILEDERRORS" value="1" />
        
          <environmentVariable name="WEBCONNECTION_USELIVERELOAD" value="False" />
          <environmentVariable name="WEBCONNECTION_OPENBROWSER" value="False" />
          <environmentVariable name="WEBCONNECTION_SHOWURLS" value="False" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>   
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I have also checked that I don’t have any references to any .NET core 2.0 .dlls as per [Rick Strahl blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Jan/14/ASPNET-Core-IIS-InProcess-Hosting-Issues-in-NET-Core-31)

Comment: Is this app sharing an iis app pool, or is it the only app in the pool?

Comment: I found out that the error was actually a stack overflow. The issue was that .net core IOC blew up in our code due to questionable architectural issue that worked in .net core 3.0 but not in 3.1

Comment: I recently come across the similar situation, from the dump collected on the crash is compareinfo.windows.cs - GetHashCodeOfStringCore , `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCD58E183D (kernel32.dll) in w3wp.exe.14184.dmp: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000213BE736C8). occurred`

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the issue was at the design or dependency injection? Was wondering, since we also had the similar issue. Appreciate any response

Comment: Precisely as you did, "0xC00000FD: Stack overflow" there you have a stack overflow issue. Then I just removed all but one controller. Still had the issue. Then removed one middleware and injected service till I found out that it was my database auditing code that was broken.